# Find the range of values of k

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find the range of values of $k$ for which the equation

$$x^2-2kx+k^2-2k=6$$

has real roots. Find the roots in terms of $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: @VijayRaghavan
Ok, This is what I got so far
x^2-2kx+k^2-2k-6=0
b^2-4ac>0
(-2k)^2-4(1)(k^2-2k-6)>0
4k^2-4k^2+8k+24>0
8k+24>0
8k>-24
k>-3
But I can't find the second answer which is k +- square2k+6

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-2kx+k^2-2k-6 = (x-k)^2-2k-6.$$Hence the equation has real roots iff
$$
-2k-6\le 0\iff k\ge -3.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can solve quadratic equations? You should consider $k$ as a parameter, (think of it like any number). Also you could substitute $k^2-2k \to q$ and solve for $x$, if the constant term $k^2-2k$ bears problems.
So if you know how to solve quadratic equations of the form 
$$x^2 + px + q$$
then this is nothing else: $p = -2k$ and $q=k^2-2k$

Secondly, the solution of the equation is:

$$x_{1/2} = -\frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{p}{2})^2 -q}$$